# What type to return?

Tags: java, methods

Consider a method which produces different types of results. In my case it's either an ArrayList or an Integer (pseudo code):

```
int a = ... // value for a comes from another function

public ArrayList compute(){ // return either ArrayList or Integer
    if(a==1){
        ArrayList result = new Arraylist()
        for(int i=0; i<=something; i++){
            arr.add(...);   
        }    
    }
    if(a==2){
        int result;
        result = somethingElse;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Depending on the result of `a`, the result of `result` comes either from a loop and loads the results into an ArrayList, or in the second case it will just be a single number.

What type should the method return?

Comment: You can return a `List<Integer>` **and** use `Collections.singletionList(int)` for the case of single value. But what would you do with that result ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return a `List<Integer>`. For a single integer simply return a list with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to returning a List (but "functionally" the same),

```
public void compute(List<Integer> result){
    // add/remove/set the given list,
}
```

And although this looks like a bad design in general, you may in this case actually return a value that indicates if a "list" or a single value (a list with one element) is returned.

```
public boolean compute(List<Integer> result){ ...
```

Or, better, the length of the list (depends on what you're really trying to achieve):

```
public int compute(List<Integer> result){
    ...
    return result.size();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the signature of the method to be `public Object compute()`, so that you can return both `ArrayList`s and `Integer`s, but I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to do this.

It just means that whenever you call `compute()`, you're going to need to check the type of the `Object` that you received, e.g.

```
Object result = compute();
if(result instanceof ArrayList) {
    // Do ArrayList stuff
} elseif(result instanceof Integer) {
    // Do Integer stuff
}
```

Note: `Object` is the super class for all objects in Java, so if there is a time where you may want to return lots of different things, you can use `Object`. But the better solution may be to create an Interface, if the things you're returning will have something in common.

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: instanceof is a solution of last resort, and there are plenty of other options here...

Comment: I just wanted to answer in a more general sense, if there was a case where someone would want to have more than one different return type. But in this particular case, @Reimeus' answer makes the most sense.

Comment: Rather than `Object`, to achieve the same one would create something like `interface ComputeResult { boolean isList(); List<Integer> getList(); int getValue(); ... }` and have the `compute` method return a type of `ComputeResult`, just to avoid putting all this work into all clients; there is also a performance gain to be had by doing this.

Comment: Yep, that's why I added that at the bottom of my answer. Well, not the code part, but a link to what an Interface is.